# two frameworks with the same class conflicting

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap and [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/modals.html)and I want to show a modal dialog on a listener:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="sendPostDialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But two dialogs pop. The Bootstrap one, and the Materialize one.

I want to display the Bootstrap one. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using both Bootstrap and Materialize together?

Comment: Is it not good to mix frameworks? I started with bootstrap and implemented Materialize mid way

Comment: if there is an answer to this, it'll depend on which one you want to display

Comment: I want the one from Bootstrap

Comment: Well if you use both Bootstrap and Materialize together, you're most likely going to get namespace collisions if Materialize and Bootstrap use the same names for classes and such (similar to the problem here). Ideally you would want to just go with one since they both are pretty full-featured.